# Js преобразование строки в число типа float

Tags: javascript

Как преобразовать строку такого вида 13348490000

в число с плавающей точкой?
p.s Число прилетает с яндекс директа, число должно быть
13 348.50

Пробовал через: NumberFormat

```
let a = '13348490000';
new Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU').format(a)
```

Но выходит не тот результат, много нолей

Comment: тут никак, надо знать кол-во разрядов

Comment: разделите на 10тыс сначала, потом определитесь какое там округление.

Comment: @teran наверное все же на 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто разделите на 10 в нужной степени. Приведение типов сделает свое дело

```
const a = '13348490000';
const b = a / 1000000; // 13348.49
```

Если нужно именно округлить до 0.1, тогда

```
const b = Math.round(a/1e5)/10; // 13348.5
const c = b.toFixed(2); // "13348.50" (строка)
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваш вариант работает прекрасно